# With Scilab execution paused, how can I find out which point it is at?

Tags: debugging, execution, scilab

When I put a "pause" command into my program, I can precede it with a disp("Just finished averaging") or something of the kind, so I can read on the console which "pause" I am at.

But when I lose my patience with a program that's taking forever to complete, and hit Ctrl-C to see what is going on, I cannot see a way of finding out which code line I interrupted it at. The "whereami" command tells me I am in pause, which is obviously true but hardly helpful; it's like a GPS device telling me I'm in the driver seat. Oh yeah, I figured that myself, thank you Captain.

I am tempted to create a dedicated variable, say MyApproximateCurrentCodeLine, and updating it every few lines of code with hard-wired substitution commands. This would work but would take a lot of time to write, a similar amount of time to remove when I'm done, and would have to be repeated with every program I need to debug. Not to mention it's just plain ugly.

Is there a better way of finding the current execution point?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have interrupted the program

```
[linenum, callername] = where()
```

will give you the full calling tree.

S.